# Too bright HEX color

Tags: color, cmyk, color-conversion, branding, hex

I've stumbled upon a problem while redesigning a Xd-mockup for a company I work for. They are using the CMYK 56,4,100,0 for alle their offline marketing, which works great for that purpose. But when I type in the HEX number for the same color (#70F500), I'm given a very very bright green. Almost too bright and to that point where it isn't pleasing to look at on at darker background.

So my question is whether it is allowed to change the HEX color to a less bright for the website - even though the brand manual says the HEX is #70F500?

Comment: What color profile is attached to the CMYK value? I mean the conversion your using seems imposiibly bright, but they dont need to match offcourse

Comment: That RGB colour isn't even remotely similar to the CMYK colour. Looks like an error to me. It's also out of gamut for CMYK printing.  If there's a problem, I think you probably need speak to your client about their brand manual, and ask them what they would like you to do.

Answer (score 2):

When I come across a horrible mismatch, such as this, I ignore the apparent incorrect color and use a value which more closely resembles the color from the *correct* color breakout.

So **Yes**. I change the HEX when I see this happening.

If at all possible I *do* check things like the client's web presence or any marketing materials to confirm I don't see the apparent incorrect color anywhere. I also mention this to the client  1) so they can be aware there's a possible error in their brand guideline or... 2) on the wildly, off-chance, they really *do* want that apparent incorrect color.

---

Hex colors **are** RGB color. Some don't realize that.

Converting between color models is rarely 100% accurate and can often take *visual* adjustment.

On *my system*, using your CMYK values (56/4/100/0) results in a HEX of #81b948. Which appears very similar, but nowhere close to #70F500.  Note that #81b948 is a direct result of **my** color profiles. That exact hex value may not be the same on *any* other system where the auto-conversion is concerned.

[image]

I've OFTEN seen poor color conversions in branding guidelines similar to this. It's not impossible that someone, creating the guidelines, mistyped a value. Or merely used an auto-conversion value which they never *actually* checked. This also can *often* happen if one starts with a Pantone color.. then auto-converts spot to CMYK, then spot to RGB.. again without ever *actually* checking the color appearance. Spot auto-conversions tend to result in more mismatches in my experience.

Comment: I've seen so many errors and inaccuracies in branding guidelines that I'm always suspicious now. It can be such a dilemma. Should I follow the guidelines as instructed or make something that actually looks right? Involving the client often is often a bureaucratic mess as they aren't into the technical details and can't understand how their expensive guidelines could be wrong. I guess creating something that looks coherent with the client's other materials should be the aim.